# Loading Image in onStart() function in android

Tags: java, android

I am developping an app and i want to display a few images which indicates the current hour and minutes in onStart() fuction when i run my code the images which belongs the current minute are shown but the images which belongs the hour are not shown.Anybody can help?

Here is my code:

```
public void onStart(){

        super.onStart();

        broadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)==0){


                    kimyacaTime.setText("\n"+sdFormat.format(new Date()));
                    splitKimyacaTime=kimyacaTime.getText().toString();
                    arrayOfKimyaca=splitKimyacaTime.split(":");

                    if(arrayOfKimyaca[0].equals("19")){
                        kimyacaImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.li_3);
                        kimyacaImage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.he_2);
                    }



                    if(arrayOfKimyaca[1].equals("11")){
                        regularExpression.setText(":"); 
                        kimyacaImage3.setImageResource(R.drawable.h_1);
                        kimyacaImage4.setImageResource(R.drawable.h_1);
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));



    }
```

Comment: is kumyacaTime's value always equal to "19:11"?

Comment: of course it's not now it's 19 so

Comment: `kimyacaTime.setText("\n"+sdFormat.format(new Date()));`. Please show what is displayed in the TextView. Is kimyacaTime a TextView? You did not tell.

Comment: `equals("19")`. It will equal `equals("\n19")`.

Comment: :D you are right thankss alot for your help